Convex sets in general metric spaces
A set of points in a Euclidean space is called convex if it contains every line segment between two points in the set. An equivalent definition is:

a set $C$ is convex if for every two points $x,y \in C$, the shortest path connecting $x$ and $y$ is contained in $C$.

I am trying to extend this definition to more general metric spaces. In general, there may be many shortest paths connecting the same two points. For example, in the taxicab metric, if $x=(0,0)$ and $y=(1,1)$, then there are infinitely many shortest paths connecting $x$ and $y$, and they fill the entire unit square. In some cases there is no shortest path, e.g. the Euclidean space without the origin has no shortest path between $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$. I am thinking about the following definition:

In a metric space $(X,d)$, a set $C$ is convex if for every two points $x,y \in C$, all shortest paths connecting $x$ and $y$ are contained in $C$.


Does this definition make sense?
Is it alreay known and has a reference?
Are there other, similar (or different) definitions of the term "convex set" for general metric spaces?


I think that this is a more common definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_metric_space

@MartinR I saw this, but I am looking for a definition of a convex set in a given metric space (not for a property of the metric space itself).

No. Your definition does not make sense.
First of all,
in your definition, a convex set $C$ may not be connected. For example, just take $C$ to be two isolated points in two different connected components of the metric space. Your definition will be vacuously satisfied.
Secondly, for paths from one point $x$ to another point $y$, you will need to define an arclength/path length for your definition to make sense. This is not doable in a general metric space. You might need to specialize in some types of metric space (e.g. Riemannian manifolds). The most general definition of length I can recall is the suprenum of sum of distances of finitely many points on curve, which is not available/useful in many metric spaces (e.g. $d(x,y)=1$ if and only if $x \neq y$).
The alternative way to do things is to consider a sub-metric space. That is, given a subset $C$ in a metric space, $C$ itself with the same metric is a sub-metric space, and you define convexity of the metric space, like mentionned in  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_metric_space.

What if we consider only geodesic metric spaces - does my definition make sense  for them?

According to the definition on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric , the first concern in my answer still holds. If two points are not connected, then all paths will have length infinity and your definition is satisfied.

A disconnected metric space can be a length metric space (defining the distance between any disconnected points to be $\infty$), but I am not sure it fits the definition of a geodesic metric space, since there is no geodesic between these two points. In any case, the definition can be restricted to connected geodesic metric spaces.

Even if all points are connected, it might still happen that two points in a geodesic metric space have infinite distance. In this case, if a convex set $C$ contains a pair of these two points, $C$ will have to contain the entire space. This is not a desirable property.
